# Renaming the apk, which has been created through android studio

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have heard somewhere, if we rename the apk file (by right clicking and putting another name) will affect the application. Does anyone have more clarification on this?

Comment: Based on my experience, it does not. Could you mention the source? Are you facing this issue when you try it?

Answer (score 2):

You're fine with changing the apk name, as long as you're not changing the extension or breaking the keystore. (This won't happen by just changing the APK name).

Please note: changing the apk name does not change 'the app'. It's about the package id (com.example.app). So basically, changing the apk name doesn't help you with installing it as a copy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, changing the name of the APK generated does not affect the content in it.

The thing is to preserve the type of the file, specifically the `.apk` extension of you need to run the file smoothly and without any error.

Android Studio packages all the coded files, i.e., manifests, java/kotlin code, XML files, etc into a single `.apk` file. Changing the name of the output does not affect the content. The name of the app that will come after installing the APK comes from the manifest which will not be affected

Neither the package name will be affected